# Proving a function is continuous

Tags: analysis

I have a problem where $f: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function and I'm supposed to prove that f is continuous. However, I don't know how to do this. I'm more used to $f(x)$ having two parts and proving continuity at those different parts. For example, I just did a problem where I proved $f(x) = x \sin(1/x)$ if $x \neq 0$, and $0$ if $x = 0$ is continuous at all $x$. How do I prove a function is continuous without equations like this one?

EDIT: I don't think my class has proved anything in the way that nicomezi proved. This problem came from the section following cluster points and in the section of epsilon delta proofs. As there weren't equations I don't know how to solve it using epsilon delta. Can someone maybe direct me to another problem that is similar to this or give me a general procedure of solving functions that don't give equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are two topological spaces, a function $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is said to be continuous if the preimage of any open set of $Y$ is an open set of $X$.

Since every set of $\mathbb{Z}$ is open (for the usual topology of $\mathbb{Z}$, the discrete topology), every function from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is continuous at $x$ iff for every $\epsilon$ there is $\delta$ such that for all $y$ with $|y-x| < \delta$, we have $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$.

Pick $\delta = \frac{1}{2}$. Then the set of all $y$ with $|y-x| < \delta$ is precisely $\{x\}$, so the conclusion is trivial.